# Customization on Abbyy FineReader through programming

Tags: ocr, abbyy, finereader

We are very new to Abby Fine Reader. When we are doing OCR by using this product, the recognized text will be transferred to text editor window. Here we would need to read the text from text editor window through programming as and when it comes to the text window.(Please refer attachment). Please suggest that how can we do this by programming? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

FineReader Pro is designed as an interactive end-user tool and it prevents such programmatic access to its objects intentionally.

If your goal is the detection of text presence: You easily could use another 'screen scraping' or screenshot application and perform OCR or histogram comparison on the captured Bitmaps to detect (Boolean) if the text appeared in the designated area or not.  Before recognition, that area displays a static "Text not recognized" message.

But if you intend to capture and export the text itself without using FineReader's export features, then there are much better tools to do OCR and pass the results programmatically, such as the [ABBYY Recognition Server](http://www.wisetrend.com/abbyy-recognition-server-ocr-document-conversion-automation/) from the same manufacturer (I can provide additional setup and integration help), like FineReader on steroids, automated OCR tool I have used in many integration projects.

Comment: @IIya: Thanks for your response. Could you provide us the more details on ABBYY Recognition Server.